# Include inside namespace not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I have 3 files inside a folder:

**index.php**

```
<?php

include ('MyProject.php');

$controller = new MyProject\MyProject();
$controller::execute();

?>
```

**MyProject.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyProject;

class MyProject{

    public static function execute(){
        include ('database.php');
        $pdo = database::connect();
    }

}

?>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php

class database{

    public static function connect(){
        return 'connect';
    }
}

?>
```

Why when I include `database.php` inside `myproject.php`, php shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Class MyProject/database not found in ...

In my case I don't want to add `namespace` in `database.php`, why this is happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: try this: `$pdo = \database::connect();` note the backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Included files don't inherit of namespace. So your database object is related to the global namespace, which is `\`. To call it inside another namespace, use the `use` statement or add the global namespace `\` before the class name :

```
\database::connect();
```

Or

```
namespace MyProject;

use \database;

class MyProject{
    public static function execute(){
        include ('database.php');
        $pdo = database::connect();
    }
}
```

More: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: you could just say `use database` no need for the `as database` here.

Comment: @mistermartin True, it's simpler. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

See the [global space](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) section of namespaces. You would need to precede any class calls within the global space with a backslash. In your case:

```
$pdo = \database::connect();
```